# JavaScript Input fields to uppercase is this safe

Tags: javascript, this

I'm writing some production code and I wanted to know if it correct to use 'this' to pass the objects to the function as I have done in my version of the code. Is is it "safer" to get the object by document id?

```
<!-- Code on Teaching site -->    
<script>
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("fname");
x.value = x.value.toUpperCase();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>    
Enter your name: <input type="text" id="fname" onchange="myFunction()">

</body>
</html>


<!-- My Version of Code -->    
<script>
function myFunction(obj) {
obj.value = obj.value.toUpperCase();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>    
Enter your name: <input type="text" id="fname" onchange="myFunction(this)">    

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: IMO I don't see any issue with passing `this`.

Comment: I always use 'this' - it allows nice clean generic functions

Comment: Your approach is more generic and thats good, but you can still improve it .Just add class and bind it.So every time you don't have to call this function. in text box you just add class. That makes your code more clean and easy to read.

Answer (score 1):

**Your solution is more re-usable. Using your solution, you can use the function as many times as you want; using theirs, you will have to create a new function for every new input element.**

I prefer your solution. The reason the teaching site is not using something similar to your code is probably because they don't want to confuse you by throwing multiple concepts at you all at once.

Also, searching for elements in the DOM can hurt your website's performance (but with a small example like yours, it will probably not make a difference, but this tip could help you later on).

Additionally, @nikunjMnage's suggestion is not a bad one either, avoiding inline event handlers is good practice, as he suggested, it makes your code more readable.

**@nikunjMnage's solution > your solution > teaching site's solution**

Here's how you would implement his solution (binding the events to classes instead of using inline event handlers):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

Enter your first-name: <input class="uppercase_us" type="text" id="fname">
Enter your last-name: <input class="uppercase_us" type="text" id="lname">

<script>
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("uppercase_us");

for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
elems[i].addEventListener("change", function() {
event.target.value = event.target.value.toUpperCase();  
} ,false);
}  
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

'this' is perfectly fine to use in production code. If you really needed to you could get the name attribute inside the function using 'this' method. sorry for the terrible puns.

Answer (score 0):

Providing `this` in the onchange attribute is correct.

---

A bit off topic:

Another option to achieve the same result (ensure the value is uppercase) is to have css decorate the input element with `text-transform: uppercase;`. This will make the text visually uppercase client side.
You can then do the actual uppercase transform server side.